# BinaryFormatter does not recognize user-defined implicit conversion

Tags: c#, implicit-conversion, binaryformatter

I have two identical objects in different namespaces that I would like to implicitly convert.  It works fine when converting in code by assignment, but errors when you I use a BinaryFormatter to load one type into another;

```
Object of type 'Name1.MyObject' cannot be converted to type 'Name2.MyObject'.
```

The objects

```
namespace Name1
{
    [Serializable]
    [DataContract]
    public class MyObject
    {
    }
    
    public static implicit operator Name2.MyObject(Name1.MyObject myObject)
    {
        return new Name2.MyObject();
    }
    public static implicit operator Name1.MyObject(Name2.MyObject myObject)
    {
        return new Name1.MyObject();
    }
}


namespace Name2
{
    [Serializable]
    [DataContract]
    public class MyObject
    {
    }
}
```

Full Stack of error;

```
   at System.RuntimeType.TryChangeType(Object value, Binder binder, CultureInfo culture, Boolean needsSpecialCast)
   at System.Reflection.RtFieldInfo.UnsafeSetValue(Object obj, Object value, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.SerializationSetValue(MemberInfo fi, Object target, Object value)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.CompleteObject(ObjectHolder holder, Boolean bObjectFullyComplete)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.DoNewlyRegisteredObjectFixups(ObjectHolder holder)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.RegisterObject(Object obj, Int64 objectID, SerializationInfo info, Int64 idOfContainingObj, MemberInfo member, Int32[] arrayIndex)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.RegisterObject(Object obj, ParseRecord pr, ParseRecord objectPr, Boolean bIsString)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.ParseObjectEnd(ParseRecord pr)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.Run()
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream)
   at Shipster.Domain.Serialization.ReadObject[T](Byte[] BlobData) in PATH\Serialization.cs:line 115
```

Comment: Your 'Full Stack of error;' is missing the actual error, it shows just the call stack.

Comment: Error is at the top so skipped it from the stack, "Object of type 'Name1.MyObject' cannot be converted to type 'Name2.MyObject'."

Comment: That is a limitation of the BinaryFormtter for security reasons.  You must deserialize into the exact same type-name-assembly-culture type.  You can see the notation in the output.